# Dielectric liquid sucked up between two cylinders with a voltage difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics

Consider problem 4.13 from Jackson's *Electrodynamics* book:

> Two long, coaxial cylindrical conducting surfaces of radii $a$ and $b$ are lowered vertically into a liquid dielectric. If the liquid rises a distance $h$ between the electrodes when a potential difference $V$ is established between them, show that the susceptibility of the liquid is
>   $$\chi_e = \frac{(b^2 - a^2)\rho g h \ln(b/a)}{V^2}$$
>   where $\rho$ is the density of the liquid, $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, and the susceptibility of air is neglected.

The implication is that gravity balances out the "pull" of the electric field. If the liquid rises, clearly the gravitational potential energy goes up. However, if a dielectric is placed in an electric field caused by constant voltages, the energy also goes up$^{[a]}$. Jackson explicitly states that the energy goes up.

Thus, they cannot balance each other and will not come to a stable equilibrium. [One treatment](http://wtamu.edu/~cbaird/all_homework_solutions/Jackson_4_13_Homework_Solution.pdf) that I have seen equates the two potential energies. This does not make sense physically as the sum should be zero for equilibrium. [Another](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~pran/jackson/P505/P505F01HW06.pdf) equates the forces, ignoring the fact that they are in the same direction. A [third](http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/209/f02/Solutions.HW3.pdf) does the equilibrium part properly, but gets the negative of what Jackson has.

Am I missing something or is the principle that Jackson is trying to use in this question wrong?

$[a]$: Jackson writes
$$\delta W_V = -\delta W_Q$$
where $\delta W_V$ is the energy change caused by introducing a dielectric in the presence of constant voltage, $\delta W_Q$ is the energy change caused by introducing a dielectric in the presence of constant charge. $\delta W_Q < 0$, as shown previously in the chapter. Jackson also explicitly states that the energy goes up when introducing a dielectric in the presence of constant voltage.

Comment: I think I may have found one key to my problem. Jackson also states that the force on the dielectric is the *positive* gradient of the potential energy instead of the usual negative. The meaning is that the dielectric will move to regions that maximize the energy. Unfortunately, it is not obvious why this is the case.

Comment: There is an upward force on the dielectric as explained in this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/351049/104696 you must not forget that the battery does work in maintaining a constant voltage across the concentric cylinders as they are immersed into the dielectric liquid.

Comment: I have heavily edited this post to make it more clear etc. Please have a look at the edits so you can get an idea of how to make your questions as clear as possible. Formatting matters, because those of us who read through dozens of posts trying to decide what to spend time on will essentially pass right over anything that's not easy to read.

Comment: Thank you to Farcher and Daniel for the edits! It helps a lot.