# Problem on liquid dielectric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

I recently stumbled upon a question from I.E. Irodov Problems in General Physics:

> **3.144.** A parallel-plate capacitor is located horizontally so that one of its plates is submerged into liquid while the other is over its surface (Fig. 3.33). The permittivity of the liquid is equal to $\varepsilon$, and its density is equal to $\rho$. To what height will the level of the liquid in the capacitor rise after its plates get a charge of surface density $\sigma$?
>
> [image]

We have been asked to calculate the height to which the dielectric will rise.
The approximately uniform field confined in the region of space between the parallel plate capacitor must induce dipole moments in the liquid (I assume the liquid to be be non polar initially). A dipole moment kept in a uniform electric field doesn't experience a net force , which means it is in translational equilibrium because of the equal and opposite force acting on the dipole.

[image]

My concern regarding this question is as to why the dielectric is rising? It should experience a net zero force in the electric field. What's the unbalanced force that's making the dielectric rise?

This is not a homework question. I'm not asking for the numerical answer. I just want to understand the crux of the problem.

Thanks in advance. [Here's how the dielectric medium is polarised.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Capacitor_schematic_with_dielectric.svg)

Comment: It's true that a dipole doesn't experience a net force in a uniform field, but this is not what you are dealing with here. The capacitance changes when a  dielectric is inserted, so as water flows into the region between the plates the capacitance changes and therefore the energy stored in the capacitor changes. This attracts water into the region between the plates.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks Initially I had solved this question from the perspective of energy changes and I got the right answer too. But I'm not able to find the force which pulls the water in the capacitor region. That's why I had put forward this question. Can you please tell how can the surrounding liquid enter this region even if there's no force acting on it.

Comment: The polarization causes a layer of charge on the surface, because the dipoles at the edge don't have other dipoles to cancel out one of their charges. This layer of charge will then feel the field of the capacitor.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty But the force experienced will be equal and opposite. It really depends on the choice of system. My system is the whole dielectric.. the opposite faces would feel equal and opposite forces.

Comment: I don't expect a solid dielectric to rise upward in a capacitor which has larger dimensions than itself.

Comment: Take a rubber band and pull on both ends: there are two equal and opposite forces, but the length still increases. Something similar is going on here, though you also have water molecules coming in from the sides to increase the volume.

Comment: Does the fringe electric field provide the solution as shown here with the second diagram rotated through $90^\circ$ and the space between the plates partial filled with liquid? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350975/capacitor-in-a-dielectric-fluid

Comment: @Farcher Thanks.. your view seems to be convincing... Although I'm not sure about this... The two problems have the same crux but different arrangements.