# Heat produced when dielectric inserted in a capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

When a capacitor is connected to battery, it stores $\frac{C V^2}{2}$, while battery supplied $CV^2$ energy. Therefore, $\frac{C V^2}{2}$ energy gets lost as heat. When a capacitor is already charged and a dielectric is inserted in this charged capacitor (which is still connected to the battery), will there be any heat produced ?

Comment: You posed this question again [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/380705/force-on-dielectric-when-inserted-in-charged-capacitor) in other words. The wording of that other question is much clearer. I chose to answer here, because there already was an answer here. Maybe you could replace the text of this question with that of the other one and then delete the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation by Ben clearly shows that the total energy stored in the battery and the capacitor is lower for the final situation than for the initial situation. Some energy has thus gone somewhere else.

The question is: Where did this energy go? And are we allowed to calculate to force on the dielectric by taking the derivative of the energy with respect to the position of the dielectric?

The answer is that it depends on in what way you let the dielectric slide into the capacitor. (I consider a solid dielectric here)

If the dielectric is slowly inserted into the capacitor, there will be no energy converted into heat at all. A force is needed to prevent the dielectric from sliding in. The dielectric is thus performing work on the object that is holding it back. All the missing energy will be transferred to the object holding back the dielectric.

In this situation calculating the force from the change in energy is justified.

Note that in this situation, the voltage over the capacitor will remain constant during the insertion of the dielectric and the current that is required to charge the capacitor can be made arbitrarily low by choosing a low enough insertion velocity.

The situation changes when instead of slowly inserting the dielectric, you let go of the dielectric and it is just left to move freely into the capacitor. In that case a large current is needed to increase the charge on the capacitor. The electrical resistance in the circuit will dissipate some energy into heat. The rest of the energy is converted into kinetic energy of the dielectric.

If there is little mechanical resistance, the dielectric will shoot out the other side of the capacitor and will be pulled back again. It will oscillate in this way, until the oscillations are damped by the electrical and mechanical resistance.

In this case it is not justified to calculate the force by just considering the energy in the capacitor and battery. One should also consider the energy dissipated in the resistance.

Note that in this case the voltage over the capacitor is no longer constant. The voltage drop over the electrical resistance will cause a voltage difference between the battery and the capacitor.

Comment: I just discovered that the OP has posed variations of the same question a total of three times. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/181869/yashkalp-sharma?tab=questions
Yesterday, unaware of your existing answer, I answered his last question "Why is no heat produced when dielectric inserted slowly in charged capacitor" he posed on Jan 18 obviously after accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because when you add the dielectric more charge will flow onto the plates of the capacitor.

The energy on the capacitor is initially:

$$E_{c,i} = \frac{1}{2}CV^2   $$

After you add the dielectric:

$$E_{c,f} = \frac{1}{2}C'V^2   $$

So the change in energy is:

$$\Delta E_{c} = \frac{1}{2}V^2 (C'-C)$$

However, for the battery,

$$E_{B,i} = CV^2   $$

$$E_{B,f} = C'V^2   $$

$$\Delta E_{B} = V^2 (C'-C)$$

Finally,

$$\Delta E_B - \Delta E_c = \frac{1}{2}V^2 (C'-C)$$

which is the amount of heat produced.

Comment: Ben, as you said that heat will be produced when dielectric is inserted, that means certainly there will be loss of energy and hence energy conservation could not be applied, but when deriving formula for force on dielectric we do apply force on dielectric, are we wrong there.  See this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuDg1_Ac1LU and also this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350975/capacitor-in-a-dielectric-fluid. Thanks

Comment: This is a re-statement of the problem, not a solution.

Comment: user121330, yes my above comment is another problem or rather it is the actual problem as I seriously was not able to understand that why everyone had applied energy conservation in that derivation for force neglecting heat. Hope anyone could help me here with it.

Comment: The problem here is that you are actually considering TWO processes. You have the process where the dielectric is being sucked into the space between the places and you have the process where heat is being produced via electrical energy. They are different processes. The heat generated is not due to the movement the dielectric but to the build up of charge on the plates.

Comment: To be more precise...
For the dielectric's change in energy

$U_1 + K_1 = U_2 + K_2$

And for the change in energy stored in the electric field in the capacitor 

$\frac{1}{2}V^2(C'-C)$

Comment: I am not getting it, you told that heat is due to build up of charge but i think that this build up of charge is due to insertion of dielectric so eventually, its the movement of dielectric which is responsible for heat and please have a look here {https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350975/capacitor-in-a-dielectric-fluid }, here the energy which I thought would be released as heat is actually counted as the work done by force acting on dielectric. Please help if possible