# How to describe the real world rise of a liquid into a capacitor?

Tags: electric-fields, electricity, capacitance

Known from a [Capacitor in a dielectric fluid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350975/capacitor-in-a-dielectric-fluid/351049#351049) a bipolar Liquid is rising into a capacitor:
[image: Experimental setup: Two parallel Metal plates partially in a liquid.]

To now actually describe the rise Δ of the liquid I consider the equilibrium of forces.

The Forces are: "Capacitor", Adhesion, Cohesion and Gravity Force.

Are there any other relevant forces?

If I now transform to Δ I should get the following:
[image: Δ =(_0^2 _0 (−1) 1/2+2(+) cos⁡( ) )/()]

with:
l    length of the capacitor 
Δ         Hight the liquid rises
_0       Applied Voltage
_0       Vacuum Permittivity
=/_0   Material Dielectrically
 Distance between the Plate
 Surface Tension
 Contact Angle
 Density of Liquid
 Gravitational acceleration

To evaluate this I did some experiments with pure Water (≈80), where I applied an isolating coating (≈90°) to the copperplates with distance (≈0.76mm).

So, the Liquid should rise (Δ) e.g. for 
100 Volt | 0.6mm
1000 Volt | 60mm
3000 Volts | 500mm

But what I observed was a Jump of around 2mm at 700V and another jump to around 3mm at 1200V otherwise and up to 3000V was no change in Δ.

Does anybody have an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: What is b in your formula there?

Comment: You are right. This should be . I corrected it.

Comment: There is a related post [Capacitor in a dielectric fluid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350975/capacitor-in-a-dielectric-fluid/351049#351049)

Comment: Interesting result: I hope somebody here can figure it out. Water is probably not the best test fluid, as its electrical properties may be altered by very small amounts of dissolved ions. I agree with @Facher's post that using energy rather than force balance for the theoretical calculation is easier.

Comment: Thank you. 

@Farcher This is exactly the post that i refer to in the beginning of my question.

Comment: @John what is the difference between going with energy or force? Shouldn't it be in the end the same equation and the same physics? 
Also do you have a recommendation for a better liquid?

Comment: @mtooling Yes, it should end with the same answer, it's just a simpler calculation. Might be good to do it both ways as a check. As for liquid, I'd try an oil made for insulating transformers: it should be more electrically inert than water.

Comment: @John I now tried it with silicon Oil, and the liquid was still jumping and not rising even close to any theoretical expectation.

Comment: @JohnDoty I just rechecked the equations and apart from a factor 1/2 the energy as well as the Force Approach leads to the same conclusion and predicts a quadratic rise of the liquid for high voltages.

Comment: This is a cool question. Something in your model of your experiment must be faulty, but I don't know what it could be. Maybe more details of geometry and materials could provide a hint.

Comment: Hmm, that the effect you measure is this small is really surprising to me. part of it could be isolating coating – this effectively distributes your voltage to three capacitors in a row. If it has a very low $\kappa$ and is relatively think, then it may relevantly reduce the voltage (but it should not harm the quadratic rise).
Also: Are your plates wide compared to the rising height (otherwise the assumptions of the derivation break – namely that the capacitor is effectively infinitely large).

Comment: (And I guess the jumps are wetting hysteresis).

Comment: I am using two 1 mm thick Glass plates as a scaffold. The Glass plates are plated (on the inside) with a Copper-Tape and above that for an isolating as well as surface Effects a PTFE-Tape. 
The Copperplate is approximately 2 cm width and 5 cm high. 

Wetting hysteresis or cohesion forces are also my guesses. But I am not sure how to analytically describe this or simulate it nicely.